# WMI Invalid Query in C# but works in wbemtest utility

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query

I am trying to create a WQLEventQuery to run in a C# applet that triggers whenever a new folder is created within a specified folder. I have used WMI before and I am familiar with how it works. I successfully created the same type of eventquery for when a new file is added to a specific folder. The weird part is that I get an exception when running the applet in debugging, but if I take the same query and run it from the 'wbemtest' utility built into windows, no 'invalid query' is thrown *when I remove the Within clause*. However, if I do not set the WithinInterval property on the WQLEventQuery object in C# code, a different exception is thrown related to the polling interval being required. Here are some Code snippets for context:

FolderMonitor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Management;
using MyProject.core.interfaces;

namespace MyProject.monitor.WmiEventMonitors
{
    public class FolderMonitor : IWQLMonitor
    {
        private const string _eventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
        private const string _isaType = "Win32_SubDirectory";

        private readonly IEventListenerManager _eListenerManager;
        private readonly IFileProcessService _fileProcessService;

        public WqlEventQuery Query { get; }
        public string Path { get; }

        public FolderMonitor(string path, IEventListenerManager eListenerManager, IFileProcessService fileProcessService)
        {
            _eListenerManager = eListenerManager;
            _fileProcessService = fileProcessService;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                path = GetConfiguredDirectory();

            Path = path;

            var queryParamPath = path.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

            //Query = new WqlEventQuery();
            //Query.QueryString = $@"Select * From {_eventClassName} Within 1 Where TargetInstance Isa '{_isaType}' And TargetInstance.GroupComponent = 'Win32_Directory.Name={queryParamPath}'";

            Query = new WqlEventQuery
            {
                EventClassName = _eventClassName,
                Condition = $"TargetInstance isa '{_isaType}' And TargetInstance.GroupComponent = 'Win32_Directory.Name={queryParamPath}'"
                WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0,5,0)
            };
        }

        public void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // when a new subfolder is created:
            // 1) Log it somewhere?
            // 2) Create a new WMI listener for that subfolder to detect file creation
            string newDirPath = null;
            try
            {
                foreach (PropertyData pd in e.NewEvent.Properties)
                {
                    if (pd.Name != "TargetInstance") continue;

                    ManagementBaseObject mbo;
                    if ((mbo = pd.Value as ManagementBaseObject) != null)
                    {
                        using (mbo)
                        {
                            var newSubDir = mbo.Properties["PartComponent"];
                            var newDir = newSubDir.Value as ManagementBaseObject;
                            newDirPath = $"{newDir.Properties["Drive"].Value}{newDir.Properties["Path"].Value}";
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newDirPath))
            {
                var newFileMonitorEvent = new FileMonitor(newDirPath, _fileProcessService);
                _eListenerManager.Add(newFileMonitorEvent);
            }
        }


        private static string GetConfiguredDirectory()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory"].Trim();
        }

    }
}
```

My event registering class

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using MyProject.monitor.WmiEventMonitors;

namespace MyProject.monitor
{
    public interface IFileMonitorEventRegistrar
    {
        ManagementEventWatcher RegisterEventListener(IWQLMonitor newMonitorCandidate);
        bool UnregisterEventListener(ManagementEventWatcher listener);
    }

    public class FileMonitorEventRegistrar : IFileMonitorEventRegistrar
    {
        public ManagementEventWatcher RegisterEventListener(IWQLMonitor newMonitorCandidate)
        {
            var scope = WmiUtility.GetConnectionScope();
            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = null;
            try
            {
                watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, newMonitorCandidate.Query);
                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(newMonitorCandidate.HandleEvent);
                watcher.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
            return watcher;
        }

        public bool UnregisterEventListener(ManagementEventWatcher listener)
        {
            listener.Stop();
            listener.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

my WMI Utility class

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace MyProject.monitor
{
    public static class WmiUtility
    {
        private static ManagementScope _connectionScope;
        private static ConnectionOptions _connectionOptions;


        public static ManagementScope GetConnectionScope()
        {
            EstablishConnection(null, null, null, Environment.MachineName);
            return _connectionScope;
        }


        private static ConnectionOptions SetConnectionOptions()
        {
            return new ConnectionOptions
            {
                Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
                Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default,
                EnablePrivileges = true
            };
        }


        private static ManagementScope SetConnectionScope(string machineName, ConnectionOptions options)
        {
            ManagementScope connectScope = new ManagementScope();
            connectScope.Path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + machineName + @"\root\CIMV2");
            connectScope.Options = options;

            try
            {
                connectScope.Connect();
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
            return connectScope;
        }


        private static void EstablishConnection(string userName, string password, string domain, string machineName)
        {
            _connectionOptions = SetConnectionOptions();
            if (domain != null || userName != null)
            {
                _connectionOptions.Username = domain + "\\" + userName;
                _connectionOptions.Password = password;
            }
            _connectionScope = SetConnectionScope(machineName, _connectionOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

my EventQuery Manager class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using MyProejct.monitor.WmiEventMonitors;

namespace MyProject.monitor
{
    public interface IEventListenerManager : IDisposable
    {
        IDictionary<string, ManagementEventWatcher> RegisteredEvents { get; }
        bool Add(IWQLMonitor eListener);
        bool Remove(string monitoredPath);
    }

    public class EventListenerManager : IEventListenerManager
    {
        private bool _disposed;

        private readonly IFileMonitorEventRegistrar _eventRegistrar;

        public IDictionary<string, ManagementEventWatcher> RegisteredEvents { get; }


        public EventListenerManager(IFileMonitorEventRegistrar eventRegistrar)
        {
            _eventRegistrar = eventRegistrar;
            RegisteredEvents = new Dictionary<string, ManagementEventWatcher>();
        }


        public bool Add(IWQLMonitor eListener)
        {
            RegisteredEvents.Add(eListener.Path, _eventRegistrar.RegisterEventListener(eListener));
            return true;
        }

        public bool Remove(string monitoredPath)
        {
            if (RegisteredEvents.ContainsKey(monitoredPath))
            {
                _eventRegistrar.UnregisterEventListener(RegisteredEvents[monitoredPath]);
                return RegisteredEvents.Remove(monitoredPath);
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    foreach (var item in RegisteredEvents)
                    {
                        Remove(item.Key);
                    }
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

the orchestrator class

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using MyProejct.monitor.WmiEventMonitors;
using MyProject.core.interfaces;

namespace MyProject.monitor
{
    public interface IFileMonitorService : IDisposable
    {
        void Initialize();
    }

    public class FileMonitorService : IFileMonitorService
    {
        private bool _disposed;

        private readonly IEventListenerManager _eventListenerManager;
        private readonly IFileMonitorEventRegistrar _eventRegistrar;
        private readonly IFileProcessService _fileProcessService;
        private string _parentDirectory;

        public FileMonitorService(IFileMonitorEventRegistrar eventRegistrar, IFileProcessService fileProcessService)
        {
            _eventRegistrar = eventRegistrar;
            _fileProcessService = fileProcessService;
            _eventListenerManager = new EventListenerManager(_eventRegistrar);
        }


        public void Initialize()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_parentDirectory))
                _parentDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPDirectory"].Trim();

            if (!_eventListenerManager.RegisteredEvents.Any())
            {
                GenerateFileEventListeners();
                GenerateParentFolderListener();
            }
        }

        public void GenerateFileEventListeners()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(_parentDirectory))
                return;

            var foldersToMonitor = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_parentDirectory);

            foreach (var folderPath in foldersToMonitor)
            {
                // Create a listener
                var fileMonitor = new FileMonitor(folderPath, _fileProcessService);
                _eventListenerManager.Add(fileMonitor);
            }
        }

        public void GenerateParentFolderListener()
        {
            var folderMonitor = new FolderMonitor(_parentDirectory, _eventListenerManager, _fileProcessService);
            _eventListenerManager.Add(folderMonitor);
        }

        public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _eventListenerManager.Dispose();
                    _parentDirectory = null;
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

So the query string is essentially 
"select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance isa 'Win32_SubDirectory' And TargetInstance.GroupComponent = 'Win32_Directory.Name=C:\\MonitoredDocs'"

If take that query string and remove the within clause, wbemtest accepts it as a valid WMI query. When the within clause is present, it says it is an invalid query. I am using an answer from [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/558c78f1-3469-42e5-878d-78cd12048def/vb-script-question-monitor-directory?forum=ITCG). Any help to figure out how to get this WQL Event Query to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I read through the article that I posted above with a more focused attention, and found an alternate query that actually works. The query string looks like this:

Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Directory' And TargetInstance.Drive = 'C:' And TargetInstance.Path = '\\path\\to\\monitored\\directory\\'

*One detail that can be confusing is that that the path value has to contain the trailing "\\"

in terms of code, my modified FolderMonitor.cs class looks like this: (changes marked with *!*!*)

```
public class FolderMonitor : IWQLMonitor
    {
        private const string _eventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";

        *!*!*private const string _isaType = "Win32_Directory";*!*!*

        private readonly IEventListenerManager _eListenerManager;
        private readonly IFileProcessService _fileProcessService;

        public WqlEventQuery Query { get; }
        public string Path { get; }

        public FolderMonitor(string path, IEventListenerManager eListenerManager, IFileProcessService fileProcessService)
        {
            _eListenerManager = eListenerManager;
            _fileProcessService = fileProcessService;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                path = GetConfiguredDirectory();

            Path = path;

            *!*!*var drive = Path.Substring(0, 2);*!*!*
            *!*!*var queryPath = Path.Substring(2) + @"\";*!*!*

            var queryParamPath = queryPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

            Query = new WqlEventQuery
            {
                EventClassName = _eventClassName,

                *!*!*Condition = $"TargetInstance Isa '{_isaType}' And TargetInstance.Drive = '{drive}' And TargetInstance.Path = '{queryParamPath}'",*!*!*

                WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1)
            };
        } 
    }
```